# Test SagePay on a localhost

Tags: payment, opayo

I get an error , when try use payment method SagePay :
`4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.`

How can I test the payment method SagePay in localhost? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://www.whatismyip.com/ to find out which IP address you have been assigned. Then go to My Sage Pay and add this under Valid IPs on the Settings screen.

Comment: I'm finding even thus isn't working. Is there anywhere to find what IP address the gateway believes my local server is at?